# Best way to get image dimensions using ImageResizer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

I am switching an existing MVC 4 website from home-cooked user file uploads to resizing files with ImageResizer as they are uploaded.

I see in the documentation that I should not use System.Drawing, but I can't figure out any other way of grabbing the image dimensions.

It does not matter if the dimensions are from the original image or a resized image, since I am preserving aspect ratio and merely need to determine if an image is landscape or portrait.

I am adding the code here that I refer to in my comment responding to @Nathanael's answer.

```
  ImageJob ij = new ImageJob(file, requestedImageInfo: null);

             int ? y = ij.SourceWidth;
             int ?  z = ij.SourceHeight;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing piece. I'm totally delighted with ImageResizer. (FWIW, I have noticed that the compiler doesn't seem to mind that space and for me it's easier to see when working on a laptop.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can store the image dimensions during upload (from [ImageJob.SourceWidth/Height](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/c4c586b58b2211ad0f48f7d8285e951ff6f262f9/Core/ImageJob.cs#L117) or LoadImageInfo), that is best, as reading image dimensions from a file involves lots of I/O.

If not, ImageResizer offers the [IDictionary LoadImageInfo(object source, IEnumerable requestedInfo)](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/e3cbd37a74e689ff68191c6129ef04de55686e19/Core/ImageBuilder.cs#L114) method to do so after the fact. Just keep in mind, it does involve reading from disk, and you don't want to call this lots of times in a single HTTP request. Put those numbers in the database.

You can always calculate the final size of an image via `ImageBuilder.GetFinalSize(originalSize, instructions)`. This, on the other hand, is very fast, as it involves no I/O, just math.

Comment: Thank you very much, Nathanael. Hope you won't mind helping me a bit more by telling me what's wrong with my syntax. I have this code first, right after the posted file is tested for null. The imagejob is not null, but both SouceHeight and SourceWidth are. I am pasting my code above in my original question.

Comment: Well, the space between `int` and `?` may produces a compiler error. You also would need to call `ij.Build()` prior to trying to access the results.

Comment: var imageInfoJob = new ImageJob(file.InputStream, null);
var imageInfo = imageInfoJob.Build();
this is how you can get dimensions of image file. ImagerResizer documentation has not examples.