# Determine If Uploaded Photo is Portrait or Landscape with ImageResizer

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I'm trying to determine the orientation of an uploaded image.
Based on this I will either one or another watermark overlay.

I had thought that I might be able to use:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = base.Request.Files["photo"];
ImageResizer.ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(file,requestedImageInfo: null);

i.SourceWidth
i.SourceHeight
```

But these are always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `.Build()` on your ImageJob to make anything happen. It's just a descriptor until executed.

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878738/best-way-to-get-image-dimensions-using-imageresizer).