# Imageresizer : cropping square with maximum image width

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I'm trying to get Imageresizer to crop my image as a square and maintain the maximum possible width(I don't want to set the width or height to resize the image).

For example if I have an image with the size of 600x400px the larges possible square is 400x400px or if the image is 812x423 it should be 423x423px after cropping. How can I make it happen?

In the documentation I only find instruction on how to crop an image when specify the desired width and height: example, width=100&height=100&crop=auto.

Comment: So I don't really get the question but I'll see if I can clear it up - You want to crop an image to a square where the width remains the same correct?

Comment: Correct, or better: use either the width or height depending on which of them is the largest. In another words: Crop a square of the image with maximum possible size.

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878738/best-way-to-get-image-dimensions-using-imageresizer) basically explains the gist of what you need to do. Store the image high and width during upload, compare which is bigger and then use the larger of the two and place it into your `ResizeSettings("width="+largestValue+"&height="+largestValue+"&crop=auto");` Now this isn't complete code because if I just give you it you won't get anything from this. Try it out, see what you come up with, but that's basically the gist. Just make sure you convert the values to a `string`.

Comment: Thanks, I could do that. But i thought that what I requested where "kind of basic" functionality and was hopping the software already supported it out of the box.

Comment: Probably is somewhere but you've got yourself a tool and it's well polished  so why look elsewhere when the solution is in front of you. Good luck :)